# Haskell - Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’

Tags: haskell, recursion

Just started learning Haskell and
Im trying to implement a max function to find the max of a list recursively

```
max' :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
max' [] = 0
max' (x:xs)
    | x > max' xs = x
    | otherwise = max' xs
```

but am getting the error when trying to compile

> Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
>         ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for:
>             max' :: forall b a. (Num b, Num a) => [a] -> b
>           at implementingFunctions.hs:5:1-34
>         ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for:
>             max' :: forall b a. (Num b, Num a) => [a] -> b
>           at implementingFunctions.hs:5:1-34

Can anyone help me understand whats wrong
?

Comment: I assume you were doing this to practice your skills, but if you weren't aware, this is already implemented by the [maximum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) function

Comment: yeah i'm aware, this was just for practice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`max'` takes as input (based on the signature) an `[a]`: a list of `a`s. But you return a `b`. That means that you have written that - regardless of the type of the elements in the list - we can pick whatever type `b` as output we want, as long as it is a `Num b`. But that does not makes sense. If we enter a list of strings, we can of course calculate the "largest string" (lexicographically), but we can not return that as a `Num`.

Another problem is that you use the `(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` function (as a guard). But you do not specify in the function signature that the type of the input elements must be an instance of the `Ord` typeclass. So you can not compare the elements.

The minimal fix is to *restrict the input type to be `b` as well*:

```
max' :: (Ord b, Num b) => [b] -> b
max' [] = 0
max' (x:xs)
    | x > max' xs = x
    | otherwise = max' xs
```

That being said, it does *not* make much sense to return an `0` in case we provide an empty list. That would result in the weird fact that `max []` is actually greater than `max [-1]`: usually we expect the maximum of a superset to be greater than or equal to the maximum of the set.

So the `max'` function can probably be best seen as a non-total function: a function for which not every input results in output. In this case the empty list does not.

We can rewrite it to error with:

```
max' :: Ord b => [b] -> b
max' [] = error "Empty list"
max' [x] = x
max' (x:xs@(_:_))
    | x > max' xs = x
    | otherwise = max' xs
```

So now there are three patterns: (1) the empty list, (2) the singlton list, and (3) the list with at least two elements.

Writing errors however is not always a good way to handle non-total functions, since one can not see in the type signature that a function is non-total. Another wa to do it is use **`Maybe b`** as return type. This will be a `Nothing` in case there is no maximum, or a `Just x` in case there is one:

```
max' :: Ord b => [b] -> Maybe b
max' [] = Nothing
max' [x] = Just x
max' (x:xs@(_:_))
    | y <- max' xs = max x y
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Or shorter:

```
max' :: Ord b => [b] -> Maybe b
max' [] = Nothing
max' [x] = Just x
max' (x:xs@(_:_)) = fmap (max x) (max' xs)
```

For example:

```
Prelude> max' []
Nothing
Prelude> max' [1,4,2,5]
Just 5
Prelude> max' [-3]
Just (-3)
```

Comment: When you remove the `0`, it would be good to remove the vestigial `Num` constraint as well.

Comment: @amalloy: correct. I had not considered that. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Your function takes a list of something and returns one of these somethings. But the function's type signature says that it takes a list of something `[a]` and returns a completely different thing `b`. This baffles the compiler. It cannot reconcile the declared type signature with the actual implementation (aka "typechecking").

To fix the problem, make the type signature match the implementation:

```
max' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
```